# Spring ServletRegistrationBean not mapping in SPOCK tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spock

I have got a problem with the test for my custom registrationDispatcherServlet.

I created configuration class with bean:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletDispatcherInitializer {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean registrationDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext parentApplicationContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext childApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        childApplicationContext.setParent(parentApplicationContext);
        childApplicationContext.register(WebApiConfig.class);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(childApplicationContext);
 
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/api/v1/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("customDispatcherServlet");
 
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

Create WebApiConfig class with some annotations:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("info.pionas.rental")
public class WebApiConfig {
}
```

And this is my StubRestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stub")
public class StubRestController {
    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        return "Super";
    }
}
```

when in test I skip prefix it works but if I add prefix it is not works

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class StubRestControllerTest extends Specification {
 
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc
 
    def "should return exist page"() {
        expect:
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/v1/stub/test")) // not works
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks for help

Comment: Does it work, if you use `RestTemplate`? `MockMvc` is not truly equivalent, as it mocks some stuff.

Comment: Yes i tried use RestTemplate but is the same effect. Firstly i got an error with missing ServletWebServerFactory bean so i added in @Configuration `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` and then `restTemplate.getForEntity("/api/v1/stub/test", String.class)` works but `restTemplate.getForEntity("/test", String.class)` returned 500 - `NullPointerException at TestDispatcherServlet.getHandler(TestDispatcherServlet.java:125)`